# Ionic4 Angular attribute directive having no effect

Tags: angular6, angular-directive, ionic4

I have created a simple directive that works in an angular demo app according to the guide here.

The appHighlight directive works in Angular, but does nothing when applied in a new blank Ionic-v4 app.

Here are the steps I took to create this ionic project:

1. ionic start directiveTest blank --type=angular
2. ionic generate directive Highlight
3. imported ElementRef from ‘@angular/core’ and injected into
   HighlightDirective constructor as shown below.
4. set ElementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = ‘yellow’ inside
   the directive constructor
5. checked to make sure HighlightDirective was declared in
   app.module.ts added ‘appHighlight’ to tag in home.page.html

Is this expected to work as shown, or am I missing something? Thanks!

highlight.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})

export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
     el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [AppComponent, HighlightDirective],

  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.page.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p appHighlight> test </p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: In your home.page.html, requesting you to remove close tag for <ion-content>. Initially you are closing the tag.

Comment: Apologies. This was a typo. I've updated my post with the correct tags that are already in my code. Thank you!